# Background image applied to table is getting applied to all cells in the table

Tags: css

I have given a table background image using css background-image property. The cells are given opacity settings so that the image is shown through the cells. In Firefox it works perfectly but in IE all the cells(TDs) are showing the background image. How do I fix the issue in IE. Click the link below for the page
[html page here](http://shivanand.in/forums/watermarkbckup.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. I have added "td" to the selectors **tr.normalRow, tr.alternativeRow, tr.selectedRow, tr.hoverRow** and also added the property "background-image: none;".  Here is the code I used:

```
Code:
```

tr.normalRow  td{
    background: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 11px;
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 90);
    -moz-opacity: .90;
    opacity: .90;
    background-image: none;
}

tr.alternativeRow td{
    background: #f4f4f4;
    font-size: 11px;
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 90);
    -moz-opacity: .90;
    opacity: .90;
    background-image: none;
}

tr.selectedRow  td{
    background: #fff19f;
    font-size: 11px;
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 90);
    -moz-opacity: .90;
    opacity: .90;
    background-image: none;
}

tr.hoverRow td{
    background: lightblue;
    font-size: 11px;
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 90);
    -moz-opacity: .90;
    opacity: .90;
    background-image: none;
}

Answer (score 2):

All the individual cells seem to inherit the background-image styling from the table.

Adding something like

```
td { background: transparent; }
```

seems to fix the problem in IE.

Comment: This works, but the background colors given to the "td" are getting removed.

Comment: Naturally, as the td background color is set to transparent :)
That was just a quick example, the main point being that you should remove the background image from the cells by setting their background-image to none one way or another.

Comment: td { background-image: none; }

Comment: Actually, now that I looked into the code, you just can't have both the watermark and the background-colors of the rows visible, because if the cells have a background color, you just can't see the whole table's background image through them; you can think of the cells being "on top" of the parent table.

Comment: I have given opacity to the table cells. Please check the internal styles in the head section.

Answer (score -1):

Could you wrap the table in a div?

If so then you could apply the background image to the div wrapper, which shouldn't affect the table or its cells in any way :)

Comment: Tried but this suggestion is not helping

Comment: How is it not helping? provided u dont have a background property applied to the table tag the background image from the div will show through.

Comment: It works in Firefox but not in IE. I have given opacity to the table cells. Please check the internal styles in the head section.