# How to add table background image in wicket

Tags: html, css, url, wicket

Can anyone please tell me how to add table background image in wicket. Actually I've tried a lot like

```
<table background="images/logo.jpg">
```

also

```
<style>table {background-image: url('images/logo.jpg')}</style>
```

also

```
<table style="background-image: url('images/logo.jpg')">
```

But nothing works.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: there isn't anything special about Wicket here. It's a simple CSS/HTML issue. You could use an AttributeAppender to dynamically add a CSS class (or style) if needed.

Comment: If nothing is special with Wicket then why above written code in not working. But running well in simple HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you've got something wrong when you add your wicket markup to it?

Wicket shouldn't do anything with styling your markup unless you use an AttributeAppender or something similar.  What I would do is separate things into CSS, HTML, and Java files:

```
.logo {
  background-image: url(images/logo.jpg);
}
.logo td, .logo tr {  /* Optional - make sure that table background is seen */
  background-image: none;
}

<table wicket:id="myTable" class="logo">...</table>
```

Alternatively, you could add the logo it in wicket:

```
WebMarkupContainer myTable = new WebMarkupContainer("myTable");
myTable.add(new AttributeAppender("class", true, 
        new Model<String>("logo"), " "));
```

You may also be running into some basic CSS problem, and without more of your HTML markup, it is hard to really help you. But have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298041/background-image-applied-to-table-is-getting-applied-to-all-cells-in-the-table) for some ideas.

Personally, I would just wrap the table in a DIV and put the background image in the DIV.